# List restated theorems only once

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, thmtools

I like to take my notes in LaTeX, and to help my speed, I use restatable theorems so that I can quickly recall the text and re-insert it into my notes when the professor mentions it. However, the issue is when I want to use the `\listoftheorems` command to make a list of all of them at the beginning (to aid in quickly searching my notes), it repeats all the restated theorems. How can I stop it from doing this?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{definition}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems and Definitions}
\begin{document}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={theorem,definition}]
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\hrule

\begin{restatable}[Defintition 1]{definition}{defn}
This is definition 1
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Theorem 1]{theorem}{thm}
This is theorem 1
\end{restatable}

We will now restate theorem 1, 
\thm*

We will now restate Definition 1,
\defn*
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code above]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restatable theorems in `thmtools` first do a generic theorem definition which contains all the information about that theorem, and then just use that definition. The way it distinguishes the main statement of a theorem and a restatement is with the `\ifthmt@thisistheone` conditional. This conditional is false when you use `\begin{restatable*}` or `\<theorem-command>*` and true without the `*` argument.

However when writing the List of Theorems' entry, it is written unconditionally. This patch (add it to the preamble, after loading `thmtools`) adds the `\ifthmt@thisistheone` to the writing, so that it's done only for the main statement:

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\thmt@generic@postheadhook
  {\addcontentsline}
  {\ifthmt@thisistheone
     \expandafter\addcontentsline
   \else
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter\@gobbletwo
   \fi}
  {}{\FAILED}
\makeatother
```

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\thmt@generic@postheadhook
  {\addcontentsline}
  {\ifthmt@thisistheone
     \expandafter\addcontentsline
   \else
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter\@gobbletwo
   \fi}
  {}{\FAILED}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{definition}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems and Definitions}
\begin{document}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={theorem,definition}]
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\hrule

\begin{restatable}[Defintition 1]{definition}{defn}
This is definition 1
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Theorem 1]{theorem}{thm}
This is theorem 1
\end{restatable}

We will now restate theorem 1, 
\thm*

We will now restate Definition 1,
\defn*
\end{document}
```